# Develop a file reading routine in c#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have developed a file reading routine using c#.net that will read the entire file contents into memory using a suitable Data Class or structure.

I have a text file of 600MB that has RoadId and many other entries. I have to read that file using query method so I used Stream Reader in c#.net that reads line by line. But I want to know is there any other method in c#.net that will be memory efficient and less time taking or by converting the text to binary and then reading.

Not sure please guide me through this.

I am putting my code for reading whole file line by line...

```
     public static void read_time()
    {
        DateTime end;
        StreamReader file =
           new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Reva-Asus1\Desktop\DTF Test\F_Network_out.txt");
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        while ((file.ReadLine()) != null) ;

        end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Full File Read Time: " + (end - start));
        Console.WriteLine();
        file.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Data is read");
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
    }
```

// This querying method is to take roadId from user from console and display the record....

```
     public static void querying_method()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Give a RoadId to search record\n");
       DateTime start, end;
       string id =Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        try
        {

            System.IO.StreamReader file =
               new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Reva-Asus1\Desktop\DTF Test\F_Network_out.txt");
            string line1;
            int count = 1;
            start = DateTime.Now;
            while ((line1 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line1 == id)
                {
                    string line2 = " ";
                    while (count != 14)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line2 = file.ReadLine());
                        count++;

                    }
                    int n = Convert.ToInt16(line2);
                    while (n != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line2 = file.ReadLine());
                        n--;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            end = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Read Time for the data record: " + (end - start));
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No ID match found in the file entered by user");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use this:

```
  foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
  {
    // TODO: Parse the line and convert to your object...
  }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me internal working of streamreader... how it works and handles files... is it memory efficient than any other class in c#.

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadLines(YourPath)` is using using StreamReader in the background, so you can continue using it. Here [reference code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs). So if you already using `StreamReader` and **reading only by one line**, you don't need to change anything.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //You are reading the file line by line and you load only the current line in the memory, not the whole file.

        //do stuff which you want with the current line.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me internal working of streamreader... how it works and handles files... is it memory efficient than any other class in c#.

Comment: @ankita I'm not aware of anything better than StreamReader, how it is working you can check by yourself: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,b5fe1efcec14de32

Comment: Also you can put your code in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if it is working and you need improvments.